# How to find the number of uppercase Characters in a string array?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, character

I have a code that create an array of characters **(a predefined array)** and going through the array I need to find the uppercase characters and as result display the number of it.

Can anyone help me ??

I start this code but I am stuck in the for loop

```
package question4;

public class CharArray {



    public static void main(String[] args){
        char[] array = new char[]{'a','B','c','R','n','k','W','v','t','G','L',};

        int n = 0;
        for(int i = 0 ; i< array.length; i ++){
         if(Character.isUpperCase())
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your String array here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Character.isUpperCase` takes a `char`, so you only need to passed your indexed element.

Here's an example:

```
char[] array = new char[] { 'a', 'B', 'c', 'R', 'n', 'k', 'W', 'v', 't', 'G', 'L', };
int n = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (Character.isUpperCase(array[i])) {
        n++;
    }
}
System.out.println(n);
```

**Output**

```
5
```

**More elegantly**: use fast-enumeration

```
for (char c: array) {
    if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
        n++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CharArray {



    public static void main(String[] args){
        char[] array = new char[]{'a','B','c','R','n','k','W','v','t','G','L',};

        int n = 0;

        for(int i = 0 ; i< array.length; i ++){
         if(Character.isUpperCase(array[i]))
         n=n+1;
        }
system.out.println(n); // Give The Number of Upper case 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shortest way:

```
char[] array = new char[]{'a', 'B', 'c', 'R', 'n', 'k', 'W', 'v', 't', 'G', 'L',};
System.out.println((new String(array)).replaceAll("[^A-Z]+", "").length());
```

**Output:** 5